# Trouble installing ta-lib in python 3.7 on Mac

Tags: ta-lib

I am trying to install ta-lib using the below code (after activating my conda environment)

```
conda install -c quantopian ta-lib
```

I keep getting this message below, could someone help please

> Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
>   Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
>   Solving environment: |                                                                                                                                                         failed
>
> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
>   to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:                                                                              | 0/1 [00:00
>
> ta-lib -> python[version='2.7.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to.  Your current python version
is (python=3.7).  Note that conda will not change your python version to a different minor version
unless you explicitly specify that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Package ca-certificates conflicts for:

```
python=3.7 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a'] -> ca-certificates
ta-lib -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> openssl[version='>=1.0.2n,<1.0.3a'] -> ca-certificates
Package pip conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> pip
ta-lib -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip
Package certifi conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> pip -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09']
ta-lib -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09']
Package wheel conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> pip -> wheel
ta-lib -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip -> wheel
Package setuptools conflicts for:
ta-lib -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip -> setuptools
python=3.7 -> pip -> setuptools
```

Comment: any idea on this and did you progress further? I am getting similar error on Ubuntu

Comment: unfortunately no progress here.

Answer (score 0):

`conda install -c conda-forge ta-lib`
You can use it